# Получение выделения текста

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Подскажите, как получить выделение текста?
Есть функция, содержащая такой код:

```
if (window.getSelection) {
  return window.getSelection();
} else if (document.getSelection) {
  return document.getSelection();
} else if (document.selection) {
  return document.selection.createRange().text;
} else {
    return 0
};
```

Она вызывается по клику по нужной ссылке, но ничего не возвращает. Консоль никаких ошибок не выдала. Как мне кажется, проблема в том, что после нажатия на ссылку весь выделенный текст "сбрасывается" и только потом запускается моя функция. Как решить подобную проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, никак, потому что клик по любому DOM-элементу приводит к автоматическому переводу фокуса на "кликнутый" элемент, тем самым "напрочь" удаляя предыдущие фокусы ввода. Select текста - это, на самом деле точно такой же фокус.

---

В этом я точно уверен именно насчет клика, т.е события `"onClick"`, чего не могу сказать про `"onMouseDown"`. Я вам советую обрабатывать не клик, а нажатие кнопки мыши вниз, т.е событие `"onMouseDown"`. Данное событие не удаляет фокус ввода...но(!) за щелчком мыши вниз полагается отпускание, т.е последующее событие `"onMouseUp"`, что "в сумме" сгенерирует `"onClick"`, и, наконец, что приведет к удалению фокуса с текста. Мне кажется, здесь может появиться состояние "гонки"...

Comment: Может стоит попробовать по событию `onmouseup` в теле странички `body` сохранять выделенный текст в специальную переменную. Ну и соответственно при клике по ссылке, брать уже значение из переменной.

Comment: @Павел Вершинин, в смысле, "onMouseDown()" ?

Comment: @Asen Нет нет, именно при `onmouseup` тоесть тогда когда пользователь закончил протягивать выделение мышью и отпустил левую клавишу.

Comment: @Павел Вершинин, идея хорошая, только правильнее использовать событие [`onblur`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) на текстовом элементе.

@Аsen, не болтайте ерундой. Какое еще состояние гонки? JavaScript выполняется в одном потоке.

Comment: Прошу прощенья, наврал. `onblur` не подойдет, нужно использовать специальное событие [`onselect`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp).

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/nZeuc/4/).

Comment: Честно говоря думал, что onmousedown не успеет сработать и фокус с текста уберётся раньше. Сейчас проверил, всё работает) Спасибо.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, блин, потоки здесь вообще причем? Да, знаю, что выражение "состояние гонки" все-таки ближе к потокам, но я имею ввиду то состояние гонки, когда пользователь кликнет мышью по кнопке, выделенный текст "спадет" и неизвестно, что произойдет раньше: сработает ли обработчик события или выделение текста исчезнет. Вот, что я подразумевал.

Comment: по-моему порядок выполнения событий DOM строго детерминирован, хотя высоконагруженные циклы и setInterval может нарушить этот порядок, более подробно [Document Object Model (DOM) Level 3 Events Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/)

Answer (score 1):

Я знаю, что прошло уже довольно много времени с момента создания вопроса, но, если я правильно понял вопрос, то ответ можно найти вот тут: [Выделение: Range, TextRange и Selection](http://learn.javascript.ru/vydelenie-range-textrange-i-selection)

Answer (score 1):

Предпочитаю `onMouseOver`. Вот:

```js
// Получение выделенного текста с помощью анонимной самовызывающейся функции.
function get_text() {
  // Объявление переменной.
  var text;

  if (window.getSelection) {
    // Современный способ.
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.getSelection) {
    // Старый способ.
    text = document.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    // IE.
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }

  // Вывод результата, если получен выделенный текст.
  if (text) {
    alert(text);
  }
}

// Применять эту функцию к тегам, содержащим текстовую информацию.
var p_arr = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (var i = 0; i < p_arr.length; i++) {
  p_arr[i].onmouseup = get_text;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <p>тут находится текст первый, который нужно выделить, получить в переменную и вывести отдельно</p>
  <p>тут находится текст второй, который нужно выделить, получить в переменную и вывести отдельно</p>
  <p>тут находится текст третий, который нужно выделить, получить в переменную и вывести отдельно</p>
  <p>тут находится текст четвертый, который нужно выделить, получить в переменную и вывести отдельно</p>
  <p>тут находится текст пятый, который нужно выделить, получить в переменную и вывести отдельно</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Привет! у меня была такая проблема в ios safari, я решил через функцию [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) - которая отменяет стандартные действия и мы можем вызывать свои функции:

```
function preventDef(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        getSel();//наша функция
    }

function addHandler() {//вешаем на элемент
        document.getElementById("clickId").addEventListener("click", preventDef, false);
    }
```